# Active Record Rspec Query Interface Errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec

I'm working through an API for Rails and have been fumbling how to set up the associations, the spec, and the controller for my Get route.  The goal - As a user I want to get all the notes closest to my location that have not been viewed.  I know the viewed? logic is off, as is the Query Interface in the Recipients Model and Nearests Controller.

Here's the Error Rspec is giving me:

```
  Failure/Error: note1 = create(:note)
   NoMethodError:
     undefined method `recipient_id=' for #<Note:0x007fd2a40e1400>
```

Here's the spec:

```
describe 'GET /v1/notes/nearests?lat=&lon=&radius=' do
  it 'returns the notes within the given radius' do
    near_note1 = create(:note, lat: 37.760322, lon: -122.429667)
    near_note2 = create(:note, lat: 37.760322, lon: -122.429667)
    lat = 37.771098
    lon = -122.430782
    radius = 10 

    get "/v1/notes/nearests?lat=#{lat}&lon=#{lon}&radius=#{radius}"

    expect(response_json).to eq([
      {
        'id' => [near_note1.id, near.note2.id],
        # 'lat' => near_note1.lat,
        # 'lon' => near_note1.lon,
        'note_text' => [near_note1.note_text, near_note2.note_text],
        'photo_uri' => [near_note1.photo_uri, near_note2.photo.uri],
        # 'expiration' => near_note.expiration.as_json,
        'viewed'  => [near_note1.viewed?, near_note2.viewed?]
      },
    ])
  end
end
```

Here is the controller code:

```
def index
  @notes = Note.near([
    params[:recipient_id],
    params[:lat], 
    params[:lon]],
    radius: :APP_CONFIG['radius'], 
    units: :APP_CONFIG['units']
  )
end
```

Here are  the Factories - Notes

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :note do |u|
    sender_id {FactoryGirl.create(:user).id}
    recipient_id {FactoryGirl.create(:user).id}
    lat 1.5
    lon 1.5
    note_text "MyString"
    photo_uri "MyString"
    expiration Time.zone.now.utc
  end
end
```

My Models:

User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :notes

  validates :first_name, :last_name, :pw, presence: true
  validates :email, :username, :devicetoken, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :email, length: { minimum: 8 }
end
```

Note Model

```
class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: 'sender_id', class_name: 'User'
  has_many :recipients, foreign_key: 'recipient_id', class_name: 'User'

  validates :sender_id, presence: true
  validates :lat, presence: true 
  validates :lon, presence: true
  validates :note_text, presence:true 
  validates :expiration, presence: true
  reverse_geocoded_by :lat, :lon

end
```

Recipients Model

```
class Recipient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :note, foreign_key: 'recipient_id', class_name: 'Note'

  def get_recipient
    Note.find(:all, params[:note_id])
  end


  def viewed?
  end 
end
```

Comment: has `recipient_id` column been added and migrated to the database ?

Comment: Sorry Alireza. I actually haven't migrated it yet. As I'm not sure how to populate it.  The values would be multiple user Ids as there would be multiple recipients.  I understand SQL won't store an array so I created the Recipients table.  This relationship is where I'm stuck.

Comment: So I created a new migration that added the `recipient_id` column to the table which fixed the error, but discovered other issues with the database modeling, so I'm still getting the error.